# Why isn't the paintComponent method being called?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, jcomponent

The messages that ought to be printed in the printComponent method are not printed. I am having the impression that the paint method is not called. If not, why not?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    CustomComponent cc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        setTitle( "Diverse Testari 7");
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 400);

        cc = new CustomComponent();
        cc.setImage("rgbcmy.jpg");

        add(cc);
        pack();
        setVisible( true );
    }
}

class CustomComponent extends JPanel{
    BufferedImage img = null;
    public void setImage( String str ){
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read( new File( str ) );
        System.out.println("SUCCESS!");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("altceva");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("ceva");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your `Main` constructor:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}).start();
```

`paintComponent` will only be called when you `repaint();`.

Also, NEVER NEVER NEVER use `setLayout(null);`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing?lq=1).

This code will continually repaint the panel, so it will continually call `paintComponent`. This is good because it will always keep the panel updated. You could also just call `repaint();` when you change what's in the panel.

Comment: what if I repaint after I set the frame visible?

Comment: @AndrewG.H. Then it would call `paintComponent` once.

Comment: tried, I've used `cc.repaint()` and alternatively `repaint()` after `setVisible(true)`. Does not print.

Comment: @AndrewG.H. Just `repaint();`. Not `cc.repaint();`

Comment: @AndrewG.H. Try commenting out `setLayout(null);`.

Comment: yes that does the trick, but what If I need absolute positioning?

Comment: @AndrewG.H. Never use a null layout. You can make a master panel and use a `Graphics2D` to put whatever you want wherever you want.

Comment: @AndrewG.H. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing?lq=1 Null layout is EVIL